# Reading from non-blocking stdin in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, posix, system-calls, nonblocking

Example code that sets stdin to be non-blocking, then makes a read system call.

```
section .text
    global  _start

_start:
    mov eax,    55           ; __NR_fcntl
    mov ebx,    0
    mov ecx,    4            ; F_SETFL
    mov edx,    2048         ; O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK
    int 0x80
    mov eax,    3            ; __NR_read
    mov ebx,    0
    mov ecx,    buf
    mov edx,    1024
    int 0x80
    mov [br],   eax
    mov eax,    4            ; __NR_write
    mov ebx,    1
    mov ecx,    buf
    mov edx,    [br]
    int 0x80
    mov eax,    1            ; __NR_exit
    mov ebx,    0
    int 0x80

section .bss
    buf resb    1024
    br  resd    1
```

Expected behavior: program exits without printing anything because I expect `read` to return `0` in EAX when there's nothing to read (on the terminal).

Current behavior: program prints 4 random bytes as `read` returns `-11` when nothing was passed to stdin.

```
$ strace ./nonblocking 
execve("./nonblocking", ["./nonblocking"], 0x7fff196fcb40 /* 53 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=4112759 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
read(0, 0x804a000, 1024)                = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4294967285����) = 4096
exit(0)                                 = ?
```

(Editor's note: `\0` prints as zero-width on terminals, but the 4 *non-zero* bytes the question is talking about are the `-11` dword in `br`, starting 1024 bytes into the output.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201603/discussion-on-question-by-debos99-reading-from-non-blocking-stdin-in-nasm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux system calls return `-errno` values on error.  `read` is returning `-EAGAIN` as documented for non-blocking I/O on a device that has no bytes "ready", thus EAX = `-11` which has 4 non-zero bytes in its bit-pattern.

**You're not actually printing 4 bytes, you're passing a huge value to `write`.  It writes until the end of the page**.  Instead of returning `-EFAULT`, it returns a count of how many bytes it actually copied from the buffer to the file descriptor, even though it stopped because it hit an unmapped page.

Writing output to the terminal makes that less visible, unless you look at the strace output.  ASCII NUL (`\0`, a zero byte) prints as zero-width on a standard VT100-style terminal, but in other contexts that's very much *not* the same as not writing anything.  Run
`./nonblocking | hexdump -C --no-squeezing`   to see the 4kB of zero bytes you write to stdout.

BTW, there's no point in storing EAX to memory just to reload it again.  Just `mov edx, eax`.

---

**You only get EOF on a TTY when the user types control-D**.  (Assuming "cooked" mode and default `stty` settings).

**Non-blocking doesn't turn no-data-ready into EOF**; that would make it impossible to distinguish actual end of file!  (Non-blocking I/O on a regular file will give you EOF at the end of the file, or `-EAGAIN` if the file hasn't been fetched from disk yet so you'd have to block on I/O.)

**The situations where `read` returns `0` (meaning EOF) are the same for blocking and non-blocking `read`.**

If blocking `read` would sit there waiting for the user to type something (and "submit" it in line-buffered cooked mode with return or control-D), non-blocking `read` will return `-EAGAIN`.

From the Linux [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) man page:

> `EAGAIN`
>      The file descriptor fd refers to a file other than a socket
>                 and has been marked nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read
>                 would block.  See open(2) for further details on the
>                 O_NONBLOCK flag.

Comment: Can you tell me why my code works when I'm using stack? `edx` still has `-11` when calling `write`. The only difference is `strace` output where everything stays the same except these 4 non-zero bytes are removed. Is it something wrong with variable definition or moving value?

Comment: @DeBos99: Your code *doesn't* work.  Like I edited into your question, a zero byte prints as zero width instead of garbage on a terminal, but if you redirected your output to a file or ran `./nonblocking | hexdump -C --no-squeezing` it would be very obvious that you're still printing the same amount of garbage, just with different contents.  (Also, why would you use the stack?  You can just copy from one register to another.)

Comment: I edited code (not in question, only on my machine) and it only prints these zero bytes (I see nothing in terminal). I redirected output to file (i.e. `./test > a`) and file `a` has nothing in it so I assumed everything is fine now. I used stack, cause if I will add some code between `read` and `write` I will not have to change my code, but you would have to change yours as registers would change between these two functions.

Comment: @DeBos99: Did you assemble+link your code as 64-bit?  If so, and you used a *buffer* on the stack, then read and write just return `-EFAULT` without doing anything.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Notice the strace output I edited into your question includes `Process PID=4112759 runs in 32 bit mode.`  If you don't have that, then stack addresses will be outside the low 32 bits and the 32-bit int 0x80 ABI will truncate them.

Comment: I run following commands: `nasm -f elf32 test.asm` and `ld -m elf_i386 test.o -o test` so its 32-bit. I have `Process ... runs in 32 bit mode` in `strace` output.

Comment: @DeBos99: ok, I took your word for it that the file was empty.  But you also said the `strace` output only changed in having all zeros instead of zeros + 4 bytes of non-zero garbage.  It's impossible for both things to be true unless your filesystem is full.  `ls -l` output should be `4096 Oct 30 10:40 a` if your `strace` output really still has a 4kiB write. (Or smaller if your buffer isn't right at the start of a 4k page). That's what we'd expect from only changing the store/reload location. Are you forgetting that `\0` prints at zero-width and doing `cat a` or something? It's a binary file.

Comment: Only thing that changed in `strace` was this line: `write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4294967285) = 4096`. It prints nothing and nothing goes to file. I check with `ls -l` and it shows `0` at the start of line before time and name of file.

Comment: @DeBos99: Ask a new question with a detailed [mcve] including code and actual strace output for `strace ./test > a`.  (And what you think *should* have happened so people know why you're asking).  You're probably doing something else different / wrong that you're not describing in comments, and comments aren't the place for extended debugging.

Comment: Ok, I will try more debugging myself now and if I won't find any solution I will ask new question. Thanks for your help.